# Unable to uninstall applications from android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, uninstallation

I am not able to uninstall apps from android emulator. (Windows xp - OS)

I know the process `(settings->applications->manage applications)`.
However in my android emulator when I click applications, its not going to the next window where I am supposed to select manage applications.

Also I tried from cmd line as ->

```
adb uninstall app.apk
```

I am not sure for cmd line whether the command is correct.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Your command for uninstall application is wrong **you have to pass package name** of your application **instead of apk name** as argument in `adb uninstall` command

Instead of

```
adb uninstall app.apk
```

try command,

```
adb uninstall <package_name_of_your_application>
```

**ADB COMMAND:**

`adb uninstall [-k] <package>` - **remove this app package from the device**

**('-k' means keep the data and cache directories)**

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the emulator and left-click the app icon and hold for several seconds until a new screen appears with the app icon by itself.
2. Drag it to the "remove app" trash can icon.
3. Wait until the screen says "app uninstalled".
4. Go back to the app screen and check to see if it is really gone.