# Android gcm: error "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services"

Tags: android, eclipse

```
I want to implement gcm push notification, i am getting this error "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services".
```

I am using (andriod api 22 and google play services revision 25)

and found following resource,

http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

When i tried to install the gms and vending package ,
Step:8: Installing google service packages; gms and vending
com.google.android.gms-7.5.74-1997312-034-APK4Fun.com.apk
com.android.vending-5.6.8-80360800-minAPI9.apk

I am getting following error,
Failure INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Checked on that found that,
"it means the application which you want to install is already installed. just remove the old one and try again."

ref:
[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when I try to install compiled .apk on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-trebuchet-apk)

So tried to unstall using following commands,
adb uninstall com.android.vending
adb uninstall com.google.android.gms
but getting follwoing error,

"Failure DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR"

I have also tried following links but won't help,
[Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-the-android-emulator)
[This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services (via Bazaar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332)

Can someone help me in solving the problem? I am using very latest sdk (android and google api) and most of the resources pointing towards older version.

Comment: Are you testing on emulator???

Comment: yes..i am using the avd with pointing to google api

Comment: Pointing to google api is ok but are you using google api image when creating avd?

Comment: yes..i cannot attach image so mentioning avd config. here..I am using Device as Nexus 10, Target: Google APIs(Google Inc)- API Level 22, CPU/ABI : Google APIs ARM (armeabi-v7a)

Comment: I can't understand,you are saying you cannot attach image but you are mentioning Google API ARM which is google api image.

Comment: Didn't get where confusion is? I have already installed gooogle play servcies from sdk manager but using that i am getting above error "update play services"..so i have searched and found some resources which tells how to install updated version on emulator.

Comment: Use `adb shell pm uninstall <package>` this to uninstall

Comment: Tried that as well..but same error..Failure " DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR"

Comment: Try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11591859/2715073)

Comment: Yes..i am using the package name itself..as i mentioned above..using step 8-F  from http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step